# How to merge metadata from several copies of Oracle database into single (reference) database

Tags: sql, oracle

What we have: some developers worked (pl/sql developer) with several copies of same Oracle DB & they made changes in same pakages in different copies of DB. Changes was made mostly in packages, but tables was also changed. And one package could be modified by multiple developers :(

What we want: merge metadata from this copies of DB into single/reference DB. Is there any simple & safe way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: no.

You can pull the text of the DDL statements to create tables and packages and run them through a diff process, but then you've got a lot of manual work ahead.

The problem of course is that you have no idea which change takes priority over which other change, what package versions are dependent on what table changes, or even what order the changes were made in. The department is in this position because of sloppy development and management practices that were convenient, and time- and cost-saving in the past, but now you have to pay back the technical debt incurred.

Don't be too alarmed -- most Oracle shops i've worked in over the past 20 years have also had no source control whatsoever, and have also ended up getting screwed by it. Your department needs to get on a source control system, such as git, and invest in some training in tuning your code slingers into real software developers, capable of following standard industry practices.

Sorry, but there's no easy answer.

Comment: Thx David! Do you have any links to best practicies of Oracle source code control?

Comment: I don't think that it's particularly different from other environments. You have to choose whether to use check-out/check-in paradigm, which is the traditional sort of approach and I've never used that, or a distributed system like git will allow every developer to have their own repository and push/pull to a central repo. Developers have responsibility for merging changes and for providing code to modify the tables etc.. If you look for best practices for Oracle you'll probably come across a whole bunch of very expensive and unnecessary products.